# How to prevent absolute references from changing inside an Offset function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using an Offset function to create rolling charts in Excel.

Problem is, when I insert a row above the referenced cell, the absolute reference inside the offset function changes.

How can I keep this reference constant?

Comment: Put the absolute reference outside the offset. But with no example it is hard to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Use full column as reference like `A:A` instead of range.

Answer (score 2):

Most people do not understand that INDEX returns a cell address.  In order to fix a specific cell that well not change as rows are added, you can hard code the cell address using INDEX.  Let say for example you want to hard code cell D3.

```
INDEX(D:D,3)
```

Of note here is if you insert a column to the left of D, the D:D reference will be adjusted even if you make the reference absolute with $.  To over come that and assuming your version of excel has column XFD, you can try the following

```
INDEX(A:XFD,3,4)
```

On a side note, OFFSET is volatile formula.  Volatile formulas are not the end of the world.  They just mean they force the formula to recalculate everytime something on the spreadsheet changes.  There is nothing wrong with using a small number of volatile functions.  However, if you notice a slow down it may be due to the number of volatile formulas or array formulas you are using.  You would be better off using INDEX, which is non volatile, instead of OFFSET.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you call give a name to the reference cell, so that the offset will always have the same starting point.

[image]

Comment: The named range will move with the cell if rows/columns are inserted or deleted.

Comment: Ohh yeah, you're right. I did not understand well the question first. As said in another comment I think INDIRECT would be a solution then.

Comment: Actually, the answer offered by @forward-ed is really the best.  I did not know that would work. Also, I think it was a good question - I don't often use OFFSET because it is volatile, but I would normally not think about this behavior before reading this question.  OFFSET can be used to implement looping and recursion when LAMBDA is released and this question shows how that might just "blow up".

Answer (score 0):

As OFFSET is already volatile, I can't see any harm using INDIRECT.  You could therefore replace for example:

```
=OFFSET( $A$5, 0, 1 )
```

with:

```
=OFFSET( INDIRECT( "A5" ), 0, 1 )
```

or

```
=OFFSET( INDIRECT( ADDRESS( 4, 1 ) ), 0, 1 )
```

But putting that into a large set of cells would be a painful exercise unless you automated it.  Without more specifics, it is hard to come up an answer that would be easy to implement.